# Cant navigate to next screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigates screens with a stack navigator. The Idea is, my app will navigate from my list of chats, too the chat screen. However when I try to navigate to the next screen, I receive an error saying "undefined is not an object" on this.props.navigation. Here is what my code looks like:

MainTabNavigator (Contains my stack navigator)

```
const ChatListStack = createStackNavigator({
  ChatList:ChatListScreen,
  ChatView:ChatScreen,
});

ChatListStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'ChatList',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 
'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};
```

ChatListScreen (Where the navigation starts from)

```
export default class ChatListScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Chats"
  };

  renderRow({ item }) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ChatView")}
      >
        <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          title={item.name}
          subtitle={item.subtitle}
          avatar={{ uri: item.avatar_url }}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  goToChat() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <SearchBar
          lightTheme
          icon={{ type: "font-awesome", name: "search" }}
          placeholder="Type Here..."
        />
        <List style={styles.listContainerStyle}>
          <FlatList
            data={users}
            renderItem={this.renderRow}
            keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          />
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Chat(This is the target Chat screen)

```
export default class ChatScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
  messages: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: "Hello test",
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: "dude"
          }
        }
      ]  
    });
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={message => this.onSend(message)}
        user={{
          _id: 1
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you must make a function to handle navigation then bind it in the contractor then send it in your Touchableopacity

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Your answer is a bit broad and could be improved by adding some details. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)